# Pandas fillna method on missing hourly time point data using monthly averages

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe of hourly air pollution measurements. There are some missing values that I want to replace with the monthly averages.

[image]

I have made a dataframe of monthly average values from the same data:

[image]

How can I use the fillna method on my original dataframe to fill missing data with average values for their respective months?

Answer (score 7):

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        date=pd.date_range('2015-04-01', periods=9, freq='5B'),
        ozone=np.random.rand(9) * np.random.choice((1, np.nan), 9, p=(.6, .4)),
        nox=np.random.rand(9) * np.random.choice((1, np.nan), 9, p=(.6, .4)),
    ))
df
```

[image]

then `fillna` with `groupby` and `transform('mean')`

```
df.fillna(df.groupby(df.date.dt.month).transform('mean'))
```

[image]

Comment: Does this also work with hourly data?